# MSSQL DBO User Permission in Plesk with Godaddy

Tags: sql-server, plesk, dbo

I'm trying to restore a MSSQL database from a backup file (.bak). I'm using Plesk with Godaddy for hosting. Unfortunately Plesk in Godaddy only provides Read and Write permission to MSSQL users. When I'm trying to restore the database using my .bak file using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), it requires DBO (Database Owner) permission to complete the restore. Is there any way around for this?

I have tried to change the permission in Plesk admin, but it won't allow me. I have contacted Godaddy about it, they said user permission is restricted in a shared setup of Godaddy and Plesk.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't the place to ask for ways to get around another company's security policies. If the service you have doesn't provide the functionality you need, it sounds like you need to use a different service; either by upgrading the package you have or by using a different provider that does supply the functionality you want. If GoDaddy have told you "no you can't do that on our servers", then that is the answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking how to get around GoDaddy's permissions set up. It isn't about programming, however, none of the other Stack Exchange network sites would be able to support this either, as the problem is specifically that the user wants to avoid/get around Go Daddy's security policies.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will try with a different provider.